# Why is the library's linker name only in the -dev package?

Tags: package-management, development, shared-library, dynamic-linking

Take a package like sqlite3:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libsqlite3-0/filelist
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libsqlite3-dev/filelist

Note that the linker name (`/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so`) only appear in the -dev package. The same pattern holds true for almost all shared libraries. Why? Won't this confuse programs that tries to dynamically load sqlite3 using `dlopen("libsqlite3.so")` when that file is missing unless you have the -dev variant?

Comment: It allows the OS to inform the binary of what version is installed, so it can select from multiple installed versions without conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

The `libsqlite3.so` file is only a symbolic link to the fully versioned library file name, `libsqlite3.so.0.8.6`. At runtime, the dynamic loader only knows about the fully versioned library. This is true for most shared libraries. There are some libraries which are not versioned, and only available as `libnspr4.so` for example. However, such libraries are also packaged correctly, as appropriate.

Programs should not be trying to dlopen the non-versioned link of the library. If they wish to do that, they should instead use the `libsqlite3.so.0` filename, for example, which is installed in the binary library package, rather than the accompanying -dev package. This way the program will continue working if sqlite3 breaks API compatibility at some point, and there is a `libsqlite3.so.1` instead. Using `libsqlite3.so.0` would ensure the program would use the API of the library which it was written to work with.

Comment: Thanks, so what you're saying is `dlopen("libsqlite3.so")` is a programming error and should always be `dlopen("libsqlite3.so.0")` instead? If so, do you have a references for that statement because I've seen lots of code trying to dlopen non-versioned shared libraries.

Comment: It's certainly bad practice. I don't have a reference to point you to, but the problems with trying to load the one without the so version should be obvious. If you load `libfoo.so`, and require a symbol that is in `libfoo.so.0` but was removed from `libfoo.so.1`, then your program will break when loading `libfoo.so` when it points to `libfoo.so.1`.